# Xamarin.Forms - How To Create a Reusable Modal?

Tags: xamarin, modal-dialog, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms, I want to be able to call a method, something like `SetModal(content,...)` on any page in my application. When called, it should set a semi-transparent mask on top of the whole page (rendering everything unclickable), and then set content (passed into the method) on top of the mask. Like a typical web modal:

[image]

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [this](https://github.com/michaeled/FormsPopup). It's a reusable popup control created with Forms views.

Comment: Pretty cool! Yeah this is the kind of thing I'm looking for. Maaaaan, this isn't quite as easy as it is in web development!

Answer (score 0):

The best (most native feeling) way to do this will depend on how complex your contents need to be.

### For arbitrarily complex content...

Most similar to what you're used to with web, Xamarin.Forms exposes [support for Modals](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/modal/), mostly just like what you're saying.

I'm not familiar enough to give you a good answer on whether this will support the styling you're talking about, but that's where I'd start.

Code-wise, I'm just stealing this straight from that link, but it's pretty straight-forward.

```
var detailPage = new DetailPage ();

// ...

await Navigation.PushModalAsync (detailPage);
```

There's also support for nifty stuff like back-button disabling.

If you need to show the same modal a lot, you can share that code however you would typically share UIs like this.

### For simple choices and alerts...

This is what most mobile users will be used to in these cases (good for UX). [Pop-ups](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/pop-ups/) will render as appropriately-styled elements on each platform.

Again, pulled verbatim from that link, `Page` offers the method `DisplayActionSheet`, which lets you do the most complex of this type of popup.

```
var action = await DisplayActionSheet ("ActionSheet: SavePhoto?", "Cancel", "Delete", "Photo Roll", "Email");
Debug.WriteLine ("Action: " + action);
```

You can also just do simple alerts (e.g. "OK" or "OK"/"Cancel") if that's what you're going for.

Comment: I'm familiar with the Navigation.PushModalAsync(), but that's not what I'm looking for. That's basically page navigation - the whole page changes. I'm looking for something that visually lays on top of the current page so that you can actually see the dimmed page behind the modal content (like in my screenshot).